# Trying to follow an AJAX React tutorial with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to set up AJAX requests.  I've followed every step and installed everything that is necessary, but I am getting this error:

Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.

In this file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class FetchDemo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

this.state = {
  posts: []
  };
}

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://www.reddit.com/r/${this.props.subreddit}.json`)
      .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data.data.children.map(obj => obj.data);
        this.setState({ posts });
      });
  }

  handleFieldChange(fieldId, value) {
    console.warn(`${fieldId}: ${value}`)
    this.setState({ [fieldId]: value });
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{`/r/${this.props.subreddit}`}</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.posts.map(post =>
            <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
     );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( 
    <FetchDemo subreddit="reactjs"/>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is the mentioned tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1129563/AJAX-Requests-in-React-How-and-Where-to-Fetch-Data

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does your html file look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

You need to have this in your HTML code